# Visual studio not responding when run code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Im just trying to run a very simple code on visual studio.I created an empty project added a main.cpp like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Hello World";
return 0; 
}
```

every single time i am trying to run this Visual studio freezes and not responding.What may can causing this?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just closing instantly? try to add `cin.get();` after your `cout` call to keep the terminal open.

Comment: maybe installation issue! what project did you select while making c++ program?

Comment: @JameyD yes when i hit run button it just freezes and cant press anything.Need to open task manager to close it  after.Same with the cin.get().

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy just an empty c++ project

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Do you recommend me to try reinstall?

Comment: Try restarting the computer first.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani have already tried it but same results

Comment: May be , But try to restart your pc , if it still doesn't work then you should go for reinstall

Comment: Yes I think that i will try to reinstall and i will inform if it keeps doing the same after that